# Javassist, java

Tags: java

Делаю задание по созданию `java`-приложения. Стоит задача изменения метода (формулы расчета) без перекомпиляции приложения. После поиска в гугле понял, что можно решить проблему с помощью `javassist`.  Наверно, есть и другие способы изменения методов без перекомпиляции. Пока пробую на простом примере. Приложение запускается, но после перезагрузки страницы, т.е. после повторного использования метода, выдает ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как исправить ошибку или как по-другому в `java`-веб приложениях изменить метод без перекомпиляции. 
Итак, класс, содержащий единственный метод, который хочу поменять

```
package ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller;

public class Helper2 {
public String createList()
    {
        System.out.println("++++");
        return "1000";
    }
}
```

и класс, из которого меняю метод

```
 public String createMethodHelper() throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
pool.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(this.getClass()));
        CtClass cc = pool.get("ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller.Helper2");
        cc.defrost();
        CtMethod cm = cc.getMethod("createList","()Ljava/lang/String;" );
        cc.defrost();
        cm.setBody( "{  return \"300 \" ;}" );

        cc.defrost();
        Class c = cc.toClass();
        cc.defrost();
ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller.Helper2 test = (ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller.Helper2) c.newInstance();
        String sum = test.createList();

        return sum;
    }
```

После запуска получаю ошибку

> javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader
>   (instance of  org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted
>   duplicate class definition for name:
>   "ru/testScandJavaCafee/controller/Helper2"
>       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1085)
>       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1028)
>       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:986)
>       at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1110)
>       at ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller.CoffeeTypeController.createMethodHelper(CoffeeTypeController.java:108)
>       at ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller.CoffeeTypeController.doPost(CoffeeTypeController.java:56)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of 
>   org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted  duplicate
>   class definition for name: "ru/testScandJavaCafee/controller/Helper2"
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass2(ClassPool.java:1098)
>       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1079)
>       ... 27 more

помогите разобраться с ошибкой

Comment: А как звучит задание?

Comment: Время от времени может меняться формула для подсчёта цены заказа, поэтому
необходимо облегчить эту процедуру, сделав необходимые изменения в коде
для смены алгоритма минимальными. В идеальном случае они не должны требовать
перекомпиляции приложения :).
Одно из решений использовать скриптовый язык (bsh, groovy, jython) для этой
цели, но в реализации данного тестого задания это решение использовать нельзя.

Comment: а вы не рассматривали решение с использованием своего интерпретатора формул? написать его на java достаточно просто, а после этого ничего перекомпилировать не придется.

Comment: можно написать простенькую программу, которая будет компилировать класс и заменять его в программе. в интерфейсе возможно нужно будет ввести ограничения чтобы юзвери не ломали дров

Comment: или использовать вместо `class Helper2` интерфейс/абстрактный класс. в теле программе создавать анонимный класс с лямда-выражением

Comment: я только начинаю писать приложения, и, если вы предложите кусок кода для доработки, то буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Веб-приложение говорите? На каком сервере работает приложение: Web profile, Full platform? Можно сделать отдельное приложение расчета в виде EJB или в крайнем случае Сервлет. Главное приложение будет клиентом расчётного. При удачно составленном интерфейсе будет заменяться только расчётное приложение. И не надо самому возиться с выгрузкой/загрузкой классов, что при недостатке опыта, может быстро привести к проблемам типа утечки памяти

Comment: @MikhailVaysman кроме своего интерпретатора в интернете можно найти парочку чужих уже готовых.